# What is this symbol and how to write it in overleaf?

Tags: symbols

How to write this symbol (ξ) in latex in overleaf?

Comment: Seems to be a `\xi`, you can always look in the symbols list, `texdoc sy,bols-a4`

Comment: it's `texdoc symbols-a4`

Comment: Hello.You can alos use this site to identify symbols. http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html